# jQuery Doesn't Return Cell Content

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

Can someone explain why the below doesn't work please in as much as it doesn't return the content of the cell wrapped in a  tag? I'm using it in conjunction with the DataTables plugin. I basically want to wrap a link around the current content of the cell.

```
$('table#example tbody td:nth-child(1), table#example tbody td:nth-child(2)').html('<a href="view-aae.asp?id=">[' + $(this).text() + ']</a>').click(function () {
    $("#thedialog").attr('src', $(this).next('.dialog').attr("href"));
    $("#somediv").dialog({
         width: 800,
         height: 600,
         modal: true,
         close: function () {
              $("#thedialog").attr('src', "about:blank");
         }
     });
     return false
 });
```

Comment: As a guess, I'd say it's because `this` isn't what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this` isn't what you think it is. You seem to think that `this` when constructing the argument for the `.html()` function will be the specific element that's having its content set, but it's not - it's something else (though exactly what depends on the context of the code). Try this instead:

```
$('table#example tbody td:nth-child(1), table#example tbody td:nth-child(2)').html(function() {
    return '<a href="view-aae.asp?id=">[' + $(this).text() + ']</a>';
});
```

That way `this` **does** refer to the current element that's having its content set.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how `this` work.

In you case, `$(this)` is probably the window, try wrapping your code in a `.each()` and it will probly work :

```
$('table#example tbody td:nth-child(1), table#example tbody td:nth-child(2)').each(function(){
    $(this).html('<a href="view-aae.asp?id=">[' + $(this).text() + ']</a>').click(function () {
        $("#thedialog").attr('src', $(this).next('.dialog').attr("href"));
        $("#somediv").dialog({
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            modal: true,
            close: function () {
                $("#thedialog").attr('src', "about:blank");
            }
        });
        return false
    });
})
```